# Background image not showing for panel

Tags: asp.net, panel

i have a panel in my asp.net website

And i am trying to add image in runtime like this

ASPX

```
<asp:Panel ID="pnl001" runat="server" Height="300px" Width="1174px"  >
</asp:Panel>
```

Code behind

```
pnl001.BackImageUrl = "D:/mayur.jpeg"
```

please help. Thanks!

Comment: It's better to add image to the div, and add that div to panel.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this if you want to set background image of panel from codebehind

```
pnl001.BackImageUrl = @"D:/mayur.jpeg";
```